# How to load this viewmodel method to onClick event

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I am trying to call this `GetProductStatus()` method on a page button click event, but it's loading before the button click. Means when the ViewModel is loading, this is also load automatically.

I would like to declared this VM method "`GetProductStatus()`" to be called only when a button click event occurs.

**ViewModel method:**

```
private async void GetProductStatus()
{
    try
    {                   
        IsBusy = true;                         
        var status = await ProductStatusService.GetProductStatus(new ProductStatus()
        {
            StoreCode = s_code,
            StartTime = StartDateValue.AddMinutes(time1),
            EndTime = StartDateValue.AddMinutes(time2)
        });
        IsBusy = false;

        if (status != null)
        {           
                //Process happens                           
        }
        else
        {
            //Array is Null         
        }
        ProductStatus = status;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        ProductStatus = null;
    }
}
```

Here, the method is declared.

```
public ProductViewModel(INavigation nav, Store store)
{
    _Nav = nav;
    
    GetProductStatus();
}
```

Here, the clicked event.

```
private async void ProductTypeButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new ProductPage(_ViewModel));
}
```

Comment: Can't the logic in your onclick trigger the viewmodel method?

Comment: You are calling the method in the VM constructor, so it will be called as soon as the VM is created.  You don’t show where you create the VM, but it appears to happen before the page is created.  The simplest fix would be to call it from OnAppearing in ProductPage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to declared this VM method "GetProductStatus()" to be
> called only when a button click event occurs.

```
   private async void ProductTypeButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {   
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new ProductPage(_ViewModel));
  }
```

For above code you posted, we can find that the constructor of your viewmodel will be called as soon as you call code `new ProductPage(_ViewModel)`.

So, you can try to remove code `GetProductStatus();` in constructor `ProductViewModel`

```
public ProductViewModel(INavigation nav, Store store)
{
    _Nav = nav;
    
    // remove code here
    //GetProductStatus();   
}
```

and add a command in your ViewModel, and bind it to the button in your page.

Please refer to the following code:

```
public class ProductViewModel 
{
    public Command LoadDataCommand { get; set; }

    public ProductViewModel() {

        LoadDataCommand = new Command(loadData);

         // remove code here
        //GetProductStatus();
    }

    private void loadData()
    {
        GetProductStatus(); // add your code here
    }

    private async void GetProductStatus()
    {
        // other code
    }

 }
```

**Note:**

1.In this condition, you can also navigate as follows:

private async void ProductTypeButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
await Navigation.PushAsync(new ProductPage(_ViewModel));
}

2.I don't add parameter to the constructor of `ProductViewModel` , you can modify above code I posted according to your needs.

Comment: After clicking the button, the next page creates many dynamic label controls to display the data. So I would like to call array data`(GetProductStatus)` with the same click event. @JessieZhang-MSFT

Comment: Means first call the Array data, then create a dynamic label controls to display that data. @JessieZhang-MSFT

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean, is there any other problem while creating a dynamic label control to display that data?

Comment: No , in `_ViewModel` have array data  `await Navigation.PushAsync(new ProductPage(_ViewModel));`  so before create controls i want to call method as same click event  @JessieZhang-MSFT

Comment: Currently, the first function call is made after the page loads, and when the button is clicked, the data moves to the next page. @JessieZhang-MSFT

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite clear about your code logic. You mean you want to call function `GetProductStatus()` once the page appears,right?

Comment: `when the button is clicked, the data moves to the next page.`  When you click the button, you are taken to another page instead of calling the function `GetProductStatus()` ?

Comment: on the button click `GetProductStatus()`  is call and then the data moves to the next page.  @JessieZhang-MSFT

Comment: Yes When you click the button, you are taken to another page instead of calling the function `GetProductStatus()`.   @JessieZhang-MSFT

Comment: Is the `ProductPage` the next page not the current page,right?

Comment: Ya right not same page @JessieZhang-MSFT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249942/discussion-between-raj-and-jessie-zhang-msft).

Answer (score 0):

Set aside the fact that you are working with views and models. Simply think of them like any other `class` in c#.

If you need to tell `class A` "do something under these circumstances`, what are your options?

- Pass a parameter in constructor: `public ProductViewModel(..., bool doGetProductStatus)...`, usage: `new ProductViewModel(..., true);`
- Call a method `A.DoSomething();` after you've created it: `_ViewModel.DoSomething();`
- Use MessagingCenter Publish/Subscribe.